# How to NUnit test controller with multiple repositories

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nunit-3.0

I have a .net core API with a controller that handles multiple tables in the SQL database and I am using repository pattern design for best practice.

My Home controller's constructor injection looks like this:

```
 private IUploadRepository _uploadRepository;
 private ISalesRepository _salesRepository; 
 private ITRSalesRepository _trsalesRepository;
 private ILocalPurchaseRepository _localRepository;

 public HomeController(
      IUploadRepository uploadRepository,
      ISalesRepository salesRepository,
      ITRSalesRepository trsalesRepository,
      ILocalPurchaseRepository localRepository
 )
 {
     this._uploadRepository = uploadRepository;
     this._salesRepository= salesRepository;
     this._trsalesRepository= trsalesRepository;
     this._localRepository= localRepository;
 }

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostUpload([FromBody] UploadModel upload)
{
   uploadRepository.Add(upload); // the uploadRepository will save to db
   return Created("Post", upload)
}
```

I have added the DI for these repositories in the StartUp.cs and I have verified that the Home controller (method) is behaving as expected. It is able to read/write to SQL db.

My question is, **how can I use NUnit test to test this Home controller's Post action method?** I have multiple CRUD methods that utilize these repository so in general I'd want to NUnit test them all.

I've tried to use constructor injection for the Home-Test-Class but that doesn't work.

Thank you for your help!

Uddate:
I've added a Post method as a test I would like to NUnit test on.

Comment: what is there to unit test? all you have is some dependency injection stuff and no functionality.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

To unit test `HomeController`, you don't need to instantiate the external dependencies. You can have them as [Mock Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object). There are lot of mocking frameworks out there that can do the job for you.

"*Your goal is to unit test the `HomeController` only and test the functionalities related to it.*" Use mock or stub objects to minimize the number of external dependencies, so the test is focused on testing one thing only.

Following is a simple example to test your controller. I have also created a dummy project, you can see the code here [NewEmployeeBuddy.CoreAPI](https://github.com/iSahilSharma/NewEmployeeBuddy.CoreAPI):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Moq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;

namespace UnitTestDemo.Tests.Controllers
{
    public class HomeControllerTest
    {
        #region Properties
        protected readonly Mock<IUploadRepository> uploadMockRepository;
        protected readonly Mock<ISalesRepository> salesMockRepository;
        protected readonly Mock<ITRSalesRepository> trsalesMockRepository;
        protected readonly Mock<ILocalPurchaseRepository > localMockRepository;

        protected readonly HomeController controllerUnderTest;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public HomeControllerTest()   
        {   
            //Don't rely on the dependency injection. Define your mock instances for the dependencies.
            uploadMockRepository= new Mock<IUploadRepository>();
            uploadMockRepository.Setup(svc => svc.GetAllEmployees()).Returns();
            salesMockRepository= new Mock<ISalesRepository>();
            trsalesMockRepository= new Mock<ITRSalesRepository>();
            localMockRepository= new Mock<ILocalPurchaseRepository>();

            controllerUnderTest = new HomeController(
            uploadMockRepository.Object,
            salesMockRepository.Object,
            trsalesMockRepository.Object,
            localMockRepository.Object);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Unit Tests
        //Add tests
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a library like Moq to create mocks of the classes you need

a rough example of using Moq:

Declare the class you are mocking:

`public Mock<IUploadRepository> UploadService { get; set; } = new Mock<IUploadRepository>();`

Declare what should be returned when a particular method in your class is called.

```
UploadService.Setup(x => x.ClassMethodIWantToMock("Mock input param"))
                    .Returns(MyMockObject);
```

when instantiating your HomeController, you pass in the Mock classes you have created

[moq quickstart wiki](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)